# Корректно ли я верстаю, а если нет — то как нужно?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, инспекция-кода

Есть у меня вот такая шапка. Сетка на `980px`. Я не знаю правильно ли я сверстал меню.
Меня волнует логин, который выходит за пределы сетки. Также я сверстал поиск и логин отдельными блоками — это правильно или неправильно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 980px;
  max-height: 74px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
  padding: 14px 0;
}
.logo img {
  width: 154;
  height: 45px;
}
.main-mnu {
  flex-basis: 560px;
}
.main-mnu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.main-mnu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 27px 9px;
}
.main-mnu li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #96a6a7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.search {
  flex-basis: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  background-color: #e2dee0;
  text-align: center;
}
.search i {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 21px 0;
}
.login {
  flex-basis: 190px;
  height: 74px;
  background-color: #e94e38;
}
.login i {
  padding: 26px 0;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.login a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.searchForm {
  min-height: 449px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://s018.radikal.ru/i524/1701/57/04977bc315b6.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.search_bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  background-image: url(http://s002.radikal.ru/i198/1701/f6/b574a41380c1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="http://s019.radikal.ru/i601/1701/02/cde15f09e6a3.png" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav class="main-mnu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Reality</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/">Living</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/">Education</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/">Entetraimtnt</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/">Mobility</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="search">
    <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="login">
    <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="searchForm">
  <div class="search_bg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Второй год верстаю и до сих пор не уверен, зачем я начал это делать и правильно ли я это делаю.

Comment: Правильно всё то, что работает)

Comment: Неправильного варианта нет, но вот чистота кода - это уже другой вопрос

Comment: Учусь. Меня никто не учит. Покажи как нужно.

Answer (score 2):

**1).** Пиши ссылки с `title`,
**2).** Картинкам `alt` прописывай.
**3).** Где у тебя `search` и `login`, иконки через **псевдоэлементы**(before,after) задай.
**4).** Логично будет и логотип задать через bg(хотя не все так делают).
**5).** `body` задай `overflow-x: hidden;` т.к. на маленьком разрешении у тебя появляется горизонтальная прокрутка.
**6).** "Также я сверстал поиск и логин отдельными блоками — это правильно или неправильно?" Считаю, что это от ситуации зависит, можно и так и так.
Открываешь "крутые" сайты в браузере, смотришь код, как там сделано, и учишься.
**7).** Пользуйся валидатором, у тебя ошибка в коде `.logo img`.
**8).** На макете, меню над картинкой, сверху и по бокам виднеется; а у тебя во всю ширину и прижато к верху страницы. Нужно переделывать, задать `bg image` `body` и  опустить меню ниже. Можешь мне прислать исходник(PSD) я сверстаю этот макет и сюда выложу.

- Сделай адаптив и мобильное меню, поработай с медиа запросами. Обсуждать "логин, который выходит за пределы сетки" без мобильного меню не вижу смысла.
- Стоит изменить цвет `bg` у **поиска** и **логина**, или изменить цвет лого. С цветами в макете совсем неудачно.
- Кнопка **login** у тебя явно не соответствует макету. Делай **PixelPerfect**, используй например **PerfectPixel by WellDoneCode**(плагин для chrome), использовать легко; и таких проблем не возникнет.
- Я сам новичок, в данный момент изучаю **js**, можем общаться по скайпу и разбирать совместно поставленные задачи, вот мой емаил **alexandr.kazakov1@gmail.com**